# Why does the client need the certificate and key generated by the server in the official TLS connection given by Redis?

Tags: redis, tls1.2

```
./src/redis-cli --tls \
    --cert ./tests/tls/redis.crt \
    --key ./tests/tls/redis.key \
    --cacert ./tests/tls/ca.crt
```

In the official instructions for Redis-cli to connect to the server in the form of TLS, the redis.crt and redis.key used are the keys and certificates used when starting the Redis-server, which means that the client needs to obtain the The certificate and key of the Redis server can be linked to the server, which does not match the actual usage scenario.

The only explanation I can think of is that Redis defaults that only clients who have the ability to obtain the server certificate and key are eligible to connect to the Redis server. Others are considered to be illegal connections. I don’t know if my understanding is reasonable.